# create webservice with jersey 1.1x with csrf filter

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I need to develoj a java REST webapp using jersey-server 1.17, my resources need to avoid csrf (cross site request forgery) attack, i know that exists a class in jersey that can do this, this class is csrfProtectionFilter so i need to check every request with this filter, but i cannot understand where and how to insert this declaration, i knok that i must put it in web.xml, but i cannot see any good result yet, i am trying to modify a jersey example with this web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>com.sun.jersey.samples.servlet.resources.MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.samples.servlet.resources.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.CsrfProtectionFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>      
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>com.sun.jersey.samples.servlet.resources.MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

did i forget something? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found (months ago!), this is the answer:

```
<servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>Jersey REST Service</display-name>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.CsrfProtectionFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it to your application class, like so:

```
@Application("/")

public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        super(YourResourceOrResources.class, CsrfProtectionFilter.class);
    }
}
```